# How to pass a variable from php to a running perl script

Tags: php, perl, cross-language

I have a perl script that has an endless loop that reads an integer from the user and add it to the variable $b every time;

```
$b = 0;
while ( 1 == 1 ) {
    $a = <STDIN>;
    $b = $b + $a;
    print $b + "\n";
}
```

I have a php form that has an input-text field and submit button, and when pressing the submit button I want to pass the value given in the input-text field to the running perl script and get the last value of the $b variable to show it in my php form.

So my question is how to do this interconnection between php and perl?

Comment: Did you try exec() or system() ?

Comment: yes I tried but I couldn't keep calling the same running script

Comment: Do you control the Perl program? Can you make it listen on a socket? Or something else, like listening on TCP.

Comment: @simbabque, yes I write the code of the Perl script.

Comment: what's the status of this question, is it solved by any answer below? if so, the question should be marked as solved @VFX

Comment: @Fred -ii- Not solved yet

Answer (score 0):

You can open a pipe to a new instance of your Perl program with `popen`

```
$pipe = popen("/path/to/program.pl", "w");
```

then you can write your numbers to the pipe and the Perl code will add then up

```
fwrite($pipe, "99\n");
```

Comment: how do I get the value of $b back to php using the $pipe ?

Comment: @VFX: That is a different problem and you need to open a new question. The `$pipe` connects to the Perl program's stdin, so you can't read from it. You will need to use `proc_open` instead. Why do you need a Perl program to add numbers up for your PHP code?

Comment: Actually, I don't need a Perl script to add numbers up, but this example is  simple to ask my question, the main idea is the interconnection between php and perl

Answer (score 0):

Both perl and php can do IPC via UNIX sockets, message queues and FIFO and much more. Connecting to an already running process STDIN - if it exists and  is a named device/object - is not so easy.